Is it actually bad to mix pseudopotential types in a single DFT calculation?
For my whole PhD, I was told that for a single DFT calculation, the choice of pseudopotentials (PP) must be consistent; that is, a single type of pseudopotential should be used for all elements. All PPs should be either projector augmented wave (PAW), ultrasoft (US), norm-conserving (NC), or whatelse; but the same type. This makes a lot of sense, and it also aligns with my experience: I'm yet to encounter a work in which mixed PPs were used for the same step of calculation.
However, the Standard Solid State Pseudopotentials (SSSP) by Materialscloud (link) seems to completely contradict this. SSSP is a curated selection of PPs, and it's also the number one recommendation by the Quantum Espresso developers (link). Each element has one selected PP. And... it is a complete mix of all kind of PPs. US, PAW, NC, all are there. Even elements that commonly appear together, like C and H, have different PP types (PAW and US).
What's going on? Is it actually not a bad thing to mix different PP types?

I don't believe there is anything fundamentally wrong with mixing pseudopotentials - it simply changes the approximation you are making when removing the core electrons of the atoms in your system. It is up to you to make that decision. Your decision could be driven by convention (as you mentioned), practicality (speed), or accuracy.
SSSP has a paper associated with it that discusses the choices they made.
And there are some good papers, like this one,  on why you would want to mix pseuodopotentials.
